# why the *P from malloc return an adress?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, malloc

I'm trying to understand why the *ptr returns an address and when i try to point a pointer to that address.
the code doesn't work! i want to know what does that address mean or it's just some garbage in the heap?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int* ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("%d %d\n", *ptr, ptr);
}
```

this is what it shows:
1315264432   1315247120

Comment: The initial value of memory returned by malloc is unspecified.

Comment: *"`*ptr` returns an address"* How did you determine it to be an address? All I see is a number, which might very well be a regular integer and not a pointer.

Comment: that number looks like an address!

Comment: What makes you think it's an address? BTW using `%d` to print actual addresses (such as the contents of `ptr`) has undefined behavior. It should be `%p` and the pointer cast to `(void*)ptr`.

Comment: *and when i try to point a pointer to that address. the code doesn't work!* What do you mean doesn't work? It prints something... so clearly it works.

Comment: There is no property of a number that makes it an address, or look like one.

Comment: Well, if you didn't expect this number, what number did you expect? And why? Also, the `printf` call is wrong. If your compiler didn't warn you about it, you need to fix the warning settings. It should've been `printf("%d %p\n",*ptr,(void *)ptr);`.

Comment: The value of `*ptr` is as you say, some garbage on the heap. It could just as well be `0` but that would not mean it isn't garbage.

Comment: all i'm wandering is why *ptr holds a value??

Comment: Please explain what "does not hold a value" means.

Comment: thank you so much!!! Weather Vane!! super! Bill Lynch 4 and yeah you too HolyBlackCat!

Comment: What would you expect to see when `*ptr` "doesn't hold a value"?

Comment: All memory locations holds some value. The value of an uninitialized memory location is unspecified. It could hold any value. It can have the equivalent of `0`, but it can never have "no value".

Comment: SUPER really sum it up for me! thank you!!

Comment: @super: Per the C standard, the value of an uninitialized object is indeterminate. This means its value, when used in a program, is not necessarily fetched from the memory reserved for it. Even though the memory might have some values in its bits, the object in the C standard’s computing model does not have a value. (Additionally, it is physically possible for memory not to have a value; some electronic components might power-up in unstable states and not hold any value until they are set, although most users of general-purpose computers are unlikely to encounter this.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Don't worry. I'm under no misconception that my explanation is 100% techically correct. Answering a question is as much about meeting the person on the level of technical detail that they require as being correct in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

`%d` is the wrong format specifier for `int*` (in fact, there is no correct format specifier for `int*` at all). If you use format specifier for wrong type, then the behaviour of the program is undefined.

The mallocated memory is uninitialised. There isn't any object there, and attempting to access it as if there was an object results in undefined behaviour.

Undefined behaviour explains erverything that you can (and need to) know about the behaviour that you observe from the perspective of the language.

Comment: Re “Undefined behaviour explains erverything about the behaviour that you observe”: Undefined behavior is not an explanation; it is merely a lack of control by the C standard. Saying “undefined behavior” explains something makes no more sense than somebody from the nineteenth century saying Mercury’s precession is explained by the fact that they do not know the physics that governs it. It is a lack of knowledge, not knowledge.

Comment: `it is merely a lack of control by the C standard.` And that lack of control explains that there is no control. You observe some behaviour, that is a behaviour and it could have been another behaviour, as it could be another behaviuor when you run the program again - as far as the language is concerned.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The thing about astronomy is that there we all live in one shared universe (unless you ask a philosopher), so we can learn by observing it. The mercury that I see is the Mercury that you see. C++ isn't like that. Program runs in different machines in different implementations of the language. You cannot make predictions about undefined behaviour by observing the behaviour because there are no guarantees that those observations apply at all when you run the program on another machine.

Comment: @eerorika, We can safely assume that OP is compiling with one out of 3 popular c or c++ compilers. With that information at our disposal, we can find a much better explanation for the observed behavior than relying on the c standard alone.

Comment: @HAL9000 We could guess, but we cannot assume. We would also need to know the target CPU, and the compilation options... preferably the produced assembly to ensure we are analysing the same program on the same system, but then the answer would be about assembly. The question wasn't tagged with an assembly language tag, but C++ tag, so that's why the context of my answer is the C++ language (although happens to apply to C). Once we know of the UB, there isn't a need to go further. While I wouldn't go as far as say that would be entirely devoid of value... there really isn't much benefit to it.

Comment: @eerorika, OP had some code, and an observation. It is perfectly fine to have an educated guess on what happened. Just saying there is no 100% correct explanation, is just as useful as saying "Yes" if someone asks you if you know what time it is.

Comment: @HAL9000 Sure. My point is that just because there might be a more in-depth explanation (given more details to the question than were given), doesn't mean that the explanation is useful. For example, giving a lecture on spacetime and effects of relativity on time if were near a black hole might be correct but equally useful as "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int* ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ptr = 42; // Or any integer value you like
    printf("%d %08lx\n", *ptr, ptr);
}
```

First, you allocate the memory, then you initialize it to whatever value you want.

Comment: `%08lx` is not an appropriate conversion specification for a pointer, and merely showing corrected code is not an explanation, so it is not a good answer. To print a pointer, convert it to `void *` and use `%p`.

Comment: To be proper, this program should also release the allocated memory using `free(ptr);`

Comment: @EricPostpischil This answer shows corrected code and also explains why it is there. I won't argue about the `printf` specifier; I agree but not all implementations in my experience have supported `%p`.

Answer (score 0):

> 15.3 The 32 bit Memory Addressing
>
> - The 386, 486 and Pentium processors use 32 bit address space capable of addressing 4 GB memory.
> - These processors are still capable of using the segment registers, but Windows keeps them fixed and it uses 32 bit flat addressing space.
> - The 32 bit addresses used by Windows are not physical addresses. The applications are using virtual addresses.
> - The virtual addresses are translated to physical addresses through a page table.
> - The physical memory is divided to 4096 byte pages. Each page address begins at an address with the lower 12 bits zero.
> - Every process has an own directory page with up to 1024 32-bit entries. The physical address of the current directory page is stored
>   in the processors CR3 register, which is changed when the processor
>   switches control between processes.
> - The structure of the virtual address:
> - Upper 10 bits: specify one of the 1024 entry in the directory page
> - The structure of the directory entry:
> - The upper 20 bit indicates a physical address of a page table. (The bottom 12 bits are zero.) This references another directory page with
>   up to 1024 entries.
> - Middle 10 bits: reference one of the 1024 entry of the second directory page. This entry references to a page frame, which is a
>   physical address.
> - Bottom 12 bits: specify the physical position within the page frame. d: directory page entry p: page table entry o: offset Virtual address:
>   dddd-dddd-ddpp-pppp-pppp-oooo-oooo-oooo The contents of the CR3
>   register: rrrr-rrrr-rrrr-rrrr-rrrr (20 bits) The starting physical
>   address of the process’s current directory page:
>   rrrr-rrrr-rrrr-rrrr-rrrr-0000-0000-0000 (32 bits) First processor
>   access (directory page): rrrr-rrrr-rrrr-rrrr-rrrr-dddd-dddd-dd00 63
>   This location contains a 20 bit table entry: tttt-tttt-tttt-tttt-tttt
>   The starting physical address of a page table:
>   tttt-tttt-tttt-tttt-tttt-0000-0000-0000 The next processor access
>   (page entry): tttt-tttt-tttt-tttt-tttt-pppp-pppp-pp00 This location
>   contains a 20 bit page frame value: ffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffff The final
>   32 bit physical address: ffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-oooo-oooo-oooo

[http://eik.bme.hu/~csurgai/Mswin_en/WinProg.pdf](http://eik.bme.hu/%7Ecsurgai/Mswin_en/WinProg.pdf)

pointer value is same as virtual address